# How to check if the table is exist in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsp

How can I check if multiple tables exist in MS-SQL?

For example I want to check if these 5 tables exist:

```
(Log_2017_06_01 , Log_2017_06_02 , Log_2017_06_03, Log_2017_06_04, Log_2017_06_05)
```

I want to get the 5 tables each exist result from an SQL.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Log_2017_06_01'
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Log_2017_06_02'
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Log_2017_06_03'
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Log_2017_06_04'
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'Log_2017_06_05'
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name like 'Log_2017_06_%'
```

And if you want to check which of them exist:

```
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name in ('Log_2017_06_01','Log_2017_06_02','Log_2017_06_03','Log_2017_06_04','Log_2017_06_05')
```

Comment: @HelloWorld What do you mean? If the table does not exist, it will return an empty result.

Comment: Uhm.. sorry for my mistake that i didn't explained my situation..
I want to Select UNION ALL the multiple tables but if the tables is not exist , then it will cause error..may i have some answers?

Comment: You need to do that on the application side, not on the SQL side. First make sure if the tables exist, with the SQL I provided in my answer. If they do not exist, your application should throw the error, not SQL. SQL does not "throw" errors unless it's SQL syntax errors.

Comment: Then you means that i excute each select sql  for check multiple tables first? (In app side)

Comment: Yes that is one way of doing that.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :).. I worried about performance when i excute too much sql. So I want to find another way.. But there is no way to do that..